# Which array entry is this code exactly pointing to?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, pointer-arithmetic, multidimensional-array

I have this coding problem in C and I'm not able to figure out the logic completely. I have a 3D array:

```
a[2][3][2] = {{{a1,b1},{a2,b2},{a3,b3}},{{c1,d1},{c2,d2},{c3,d3}}};
```

Now if I write **a[1][0]-a[0][0]** then *a[1][0]* is pointing to memory location of the first element of second subset (I don't know what exactly will be the correct terminology over here), i.e starting location of {c1,d1} (that's correct I hope?). Similarly *a[0][0]* points to starting address of first element of first subset i.e {a1,b1}.

So in that sense if I write **a[1]-a[0]** then that should point to the starting location of the first subset i.e. *{{a1,b1},{a2,b2},{a3,b3}}* and starting location of second subset *{{c1,d1},{c2,d2},{c3,d3}}* which in my opinion should be same as **a[1][0]-a[0][0]**.

However when I print these two values I get 6 for the first one and 3 for the second one. Where exactly am I going wrong in my logic?

Comment: As this is a 3D array, *none* of the expressions you're providing modify the array at all (besides the initializer). `a[1][0] - a[0][0]` modifies nothing, but rather performs a typed-address-difference expression. Personally, I'd master 1D and 2D arithmetic before tackling this.

Comment: Where do the 6 and the 3 come from? Are they values assigned to variables a1, a2, ... etc.?

Comment: @WhozCraig- But I never said the operation is modifying anything.
Thanks for the advice, I'm working on it. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are thinking right. `a[0][0]` is decayed to the pointer to the first element of the row `0` of array `a`. `a[1][0]` decays to the first element of the row `1` of the array `a`.

Now, the point is ***what is the difference of two pointers gives*** ?

When a pointer is subtracted from another, the result is the **distance** (measured in **array elements**) between the pointers.

Now, It can be easily understand that `a[1][0] - a[0][0]` would give the distance between `a[1][0]` and `a[0][0]`, which is `6` (there are `6` elements in between these two addresses: `a1, b1, a2,b2,a3,b3`).  On the other hand `a[1] - a[0]` would give the distance between these two pointers, i.e, `3` (there are `3` elements in between these two addresses: `{a1, b1}, {a2, b2}, {a3, b3}`).

**Note** that array `a[][]` has `6` elements while array `a[]` has only `3` elements. `a1,b1,a2,b2....` are not the elements of `a[]`.

Answer (score 0):

Interessant question. :)

I assume you know the difference between array element access and adress difference.

a[1]-a[0] jumps elements in 3 steps.

a[1][0]-a[0][0] jumps elements in 6 steps.

a[1] decays in char* [2]. It takes 3*2 steps to get from c1 to a1.

a[1][0] decays in char*. It takes 6 steps to get from c1 to a1.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that a is a char array, then you are going to see that a[1]-a[0] = 3, and a[1][0] - a[0][0] = 6.  Even though the location (address) of a[0] and a[0][0] are the same, as well as a[1] and a[1][0].  The reason for the difference is that the compiler is doing the math, not in bytes, but in type sizes. The type that a[0] points to is of size 2, so even though the locations are 6 bytes apart, the difference is 3 array elements.  Likewise for a[1][0]-a[0][0], the size is 1 and they are 6 bytes apart.  Array differences are in elements, not bytes.